Why cups-pdf sometimes generates a valid PDF file, but usually does not?
cups-pdf has known issue that text can not be searched or copied from generated PDF files. I have tested cups-pdf in docker containers based on Debian, Ubuntu and Centos. I noticed that Print Test Page prints valid pdf file only on Ubuntu. By valid PDF I mean PDF file that contains text that can be copied or searched.
I create PDF printer executing:
lpadmin -p p1 -v cups-pdf:/p1 -E -P /usr/share/ppd/cups-pdf/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd

On Centos:
lpadmin -p p1 -v cups-pdf:/p1 -E -P /usr/share/cups/model/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd

If I print text file I get invalid PDF on all Linux (Debian, Centos, Ubuntu).
lp -d p1 file.txt

I wonder why printing test page generates valid PDF file only on Ubuntu. Test pages are located at /usr/share/cups/data. Command to print test page:
lp -d p1 /usr/share/cups/data/testprint

testprint is a text file that contains some instruction and uses default-testpage.pdf as template. Centos has different default-testpage.pdf than Ubuntu. I have not checked Debian.
testprint:
#PDF-BANNER
Template default-testpage.pdf
Show printer-name printer-info printer-location printer-make-and-model printer-driver-name printer-driver-version paper-size imageable-area job-id options time-at-creation time-at-processing

I replaced /usr/share/cups/data directory in Ubuntu by /usr/share/cups/data directory from Centos. Ubuntu printed invalid PDF. I also replaced /usr/share/cups/data directory in Centos by /usr/share/cups/data directory from Ubuntu. Centos printed valid PDF. It follows that difference between default-testpage.pdf are significant. I do not understand why cups-pdf prints valid pdf files only in one case, I mean printing test page on Ubuntu. This case proves that cups-pdf can print valid PDF. How to print other files (text files and others) to get valid PDF files?

Thank you, I corrected the typo
